# How do i Cross-compiling Qt for ARM boards like Raspberry Pi 2 & BeagleBoard-xm from Windows 7

Tags: visual-studio, qt, cross-compiling, embedded-linux

I need to compile Qt applications developed in Visual studio on Windows 7 for Embedded boards. I tried to google it but could not find enough documentation.

Answer (score 1):

You have to setup tool chain for arm as RPi and BB-XM has ARM processor. then Download Qt opensource setup .
set 
ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm_tool_chain- **command**

run the appropriate command to setup qt in above format.

For binaries

ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm_tool_chain- **command** --prefix=PATH --build=?? --target==?? --host=??

To generate qt-binaries for arm define path in above format , define your build,host,target as per your configuration and run command to generate binaries.

place these binary in your kernel .recompile it and burn it to boards.

That's it ..now you can run qt application in your board.

These all commands you should perform in cygwin or any pre-installed

VM with Linux distro.

Or you can get concepts from 
https://konqueror.org/embedded/
It may help you.

Comment: at least accept the answer or up vote it because even though I have answered correctly my answers are blocked .